# TabLayout embaixo da actionbar

Tags: android

Vou usar um tablouyt mas ela fica embaixo da action bar, como resolver isso?[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Xml da tela

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tab_Solicitacao"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/pgr_Solicitacao"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

</android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pgr_Solicitacao"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tab_Solicitacao" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Aparentemente você esta usando um [ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/) mas o problema é que você esta colocando todas as constraint do topo do layout como parent.

**Solução**

Primeiro é recomendável que você use um estilo base sem Action bar como `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar` depois adicione uma toolbar da biblioteca de suporte v7 e em seguida ajuste suas constraints. Em seguida torne a constraint do topo do tablayout como bottom da toolbar, então este devera ser o resultado:

demo.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/tb1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tb1">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Left" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Center" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Right" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/vp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tabLayout" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Resultado

[image: Resultado]

Comment: Não posso tirar a action bar de todo projeto só por causa dessa tela.

Comment: então faça o mesmo procedimento acima, porém sem a toolbar v7

Comment: ficou do mesmo jeito

Comment: Poderia mandar o xml do seu layout completo?

Comment: está completo, só tem a definição do constraint layout em cima disso.

Answer (score -1):

Antes, você tem que definir o tipo de layout em que esses elementos estarão inseridos. Tente colocar eles dentro de um **RelativeLayout** e indique para o ViewPager que ele deve ficar por baixo do TabLayout usando **android:below="@+id/tab_solicitacao"** como poderás ver no código abaixo.
Isso sairia mais ou menos assim:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

**<RelativeLayout
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_width="match_parent" >**

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_Solicitacao"
        android:below="@+id/tab_solicitacao"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/pgr_Solicitacao"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pgr_Solicitacao"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tab_Solicitacao" />

**</RelativeLayout>**
```

Comment: O problema não é o layout, o problema é que ele esta usando o tablayout como top parent do layout e não da toolbar